# Output a text file's values in a specific manner using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to look a for some specific values (such as 1 or 4) from a text file using bash. If this value is found in the file, then I want to call a function and pass it the found value as an argument. If the values (1 or 4) are found under a certain column (such as Col3), then I would like to call another function.

The problem I am having is with the code not being able to recognize that the value found is from `Col3` and calling a separate function. Its because I am skipping the first two lines so I have no way of tracking which value is under which column.

file.txt :

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  
-----------------------
row1  1     4     1        
row2  2     5     2         
row3  3     6     3
```

Note that I am skipping the first two lines of the text file when searching the file. Also note that this code is a dummy version of what I have because I just need the general idea on how to approach this.

```
function retrieve {
    if [[ "$1" == "1" ]]; then
        var="one beer on the wall"
    elif [[ "$1" == "4" ]]; then
        var="four beers on the wall"
    fi
}

function retrieve2 {
    if [[ "$1" == "1" ]]; then
        var="22 beers on the wall"
    elif [[ "$1" == "4" ]]; then
        var="44 beers on the wall"
    fi
}

tail -n +3 $PWD/file.txt | while read -r ignored c1: do
    echo "$c1"
done | while read -r value; do

    if [[ //need to check if the value is under Col3 here// ]]; then
        retrieve2 $value
    else
        retrieve1 $value
    fi 
    echo $var
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, we can read each line into an array, and the interate over it. If the field matches `$val`, then if we are in column `$col` we call `retrieve2`, if we are not in  column `$col` we call `retrieve1`. Here is sketch of it.

```
#!/bin/bash
val=1
col=3
while read -ra cols
do
    for ((i=1; i<${#cols[@]}; i++))
    do
        if (( cols[i] == val ))
        then
            if (( i == col ))
            then
                retrieve2
            else
                retrieve1
            fi
        fi
    done
done < <(tail -n +3 file)
```

Note that this assumes that the values are numeric, if not, change the condition `(( cols[i] == val ))` to `[[ ${cols[$i]} == "$val" ]]`

However, since it is a bit cumbersome, it would probably be better to restructure your functions from bash to awk, and then do the whole processing in awk, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Alias What do you mean? This loop would replace the loop that you have

Comment: This is too specific for the dummy code I put in the question, I need something more generic

Comment: What my code is doing is skipping the first two lines of the text file and its first column as well. From what you gave me, the output is different thnn what I was expecting

Comment: @Alias To skip the first two lines, instead of `done < file` write `done < <(tail -n +3 file)`

Comment: Still not what I am looking for, please read my question again because its not about reading all the values from the text file. Its about finding a way to search for a value underneath `Col3` and calling another function

Comment: @Alias So if you find in the last column the value 1, you call `retrieve 1`, and if you find the value 4, you call `retrieve2 4`? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: If I find the value 1 in `Col3` then I want to call `retrieve2`. If 1 is found and not under `Col3` then call `retrieve1`